# Azure ARM Template Parameter Based on Input Parameter

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Given a template.json with:

```
"parameters": {

    "virtualMachineName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
      "networkInterfaceName": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

How can I set the networkInterfaceName based upon the input of virtualMachineName?

For example:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name MyDeployment -TemplateFile .\template.json -TemplateParameterFile .\parameters.json
```

will prompt for VirtualMachineName and if 'test-vm' is entered, we would like the networkInterfaceName to default to 'test-vm-nic'.

We have tried adding this parameters.json:

```
"networkInterfaceName": {
        "value": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'_nic')]"
},
```

but receive the error:

```
Error: Code=InvalidResourceName; Message=Resource name 
[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'_nic')] is invalid. The 
name can be up to 80 characters long. It must begin with a word character,  
and it must end with a word character or with '_'. The name may contain word 
characters or '.', '-', '_'.
```

Comment: keep in mind that you dont need to do so, you can just use the concat function directly where you need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the NIC name under variables in the main template, instead of under parameters. Your parameters section would then only hold the 'virtualMachineName' parameter:

```
"parameters": {
      "virtualMachineName": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
"variables": {
      "networkInterfaceName": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'),'_nic')]"
    },
"resources":{
...
}
```

In the resource definition, you would define the nic name as

```
variables('networkInterfaceName')
```

Comment: Note to self: any place in the resources section that uses parameters('networkInterfaceName') should be replaced by variables('networkInterfaceName').